# JNA Java CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW

Tags: java, jna, credui

I'm trying to convert this function to JNA:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycode.winapi;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Sspi;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HBITMAP;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.ULONG;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.ULONGByReference;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Credui
 * @author
 */
public interface Credui extends Library {

    /**
     * INSTANCE
     */
    Credui INSTANCE = (Credui) Native.loadLibrary("Credui", Credui.class);

    /**
     * CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW
     * DWORD WINAPI CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(
     * _In_opt_    PCREDUI_INFO pUiInfo,
     * _In_        DWORD        dwAuthError,
     * _Inout_     ULONG        *pulAuthPackage,
     * _In_opt_    LPCVOID      pvInAuthBuffer,
     * _In_        ULONG        ulInAuthBufferSize,
     * _Out_       LPVOID       *ppvOutAuthBuffer,
     * _Out_       ULONG        *pulOutAuthBufferSize,
     * _Inout_opt_ BOOL         *pfSave,
     * _In_        DWORD        dwFlags
     * );
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    int CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(
        PointerByReference pUiInfo,
        int dwAuthError,
        ULONGByReference pulAuthPackage,
        Pointer pvInAuthBuffer,
        ULONG ulInAuthBufferSize,
        PointerByReference ppvOutAuthBuffer,
        ULONGByReference pulOutAuthBufferSize,
        IntByReference pfSave,
        int dwFlags
        );

    /**
     * CREDUI_INFO
     * 
     * typedef struct _CREDUI_INFO {
     * DWORD   cbSize;
     * HWND    hwndParent;
     * PCTSTR  pszMessageText;
     * PCTSTR  pszCaptionText;
     * HBITMAP hbmBanner;
     * } CREDUI_INFO, *PCREDUI_INFO;
     */
    public static class CREDUI_INFO extends Structure {

        public int cbSize;

        public HWND hwndParent;

        public WString pszMessageText;

        public WString pszCaptionText;

        public HBITMAP hbmBanner;

        /**
         * getFieldOrder
         * @return 
         */
        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                "cbSize", 
                "hwndParent",
                "pszMessageText",
                "pszCaptionText",
                "hbmBanner",
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And Call:

```
Credui.CREDUI_INFO info = new Credui.CREDUI_INFO();

info.cbSize = info.size();
info.pszCaptionText = new WString(caption);
info.pszMessageText = new WString(message);

PointerByReference pinfo = new PointerByReference(info.getPointer());

WinDef.ULONGByReference authPackage = new WinDef.ULONGByReference();
PointerByReference outCredBuffer = new PointerByReference();
WinDef.ULONGByReference outCredSize = new WinDef.ULONGByReference();
IntByReference save = new IntByReference(0);
WinDef.ULONG ulInAuthBufferSize = new WinDef.ULONG(0);

int result = Credui.INSTANCE.CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(pinfo, 0, authPackage, 
                null, ulInAuthBufferSize, outCredBuffer, outCredSize, save, 0);

if( result == 0 ) {         
}
```

I tried to declare `pUiInfo` in `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW` as `Pointer` or `PointerByReference`.

Function `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW` returns Code 160 ("Bad parameter).  What's wrong?

Comment: Your first argument needs to be of type `CREDUI_INFO`, not `PointerByReference`.

Comment: Thanks! I do not understand why it work with `CREDUI_INFO` and in the documentation is  `PCREDUI_INFO` for declare.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java does not have a distinction between "by value" and "by reference", JNA infers which it should use for a given `Structure` usage based by the most common usage patterns.

In this case, the native `PCREDUI_INFO` means `struct*`, which is the more common usage of structs as function parameters.  JNA will default to using the address of your `Structure`'s allocated memory as the native argument, and will automatically sync the `Structure`'s Java fields with native memory before and after the native call.

If you *only* pass `Structure.getPointer()`, then no sync will be performed and your native code will get a block of memory with undefined contents (thus your "bad parameter" error).

Comment: Thank you for your help!